# Make LazyColumn items be as large as the largest item in the list

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable
fun PreviewLayout() {
    fun getRandomString(length: Int): String {
        val allowedChars = ('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z') + ('0'..'9')
        return (1..length)
            .map { allowedChars.random() }
            .joinToString("")
    }

    val horizontalScrollState = rememberScrollState()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .wrapContentWidth()
            .horizontalScroll(horizontalScrollState)
    ) {
        items(5) { index ->
            Text(
                text = getRandomString((index + 1) * 4).uppercase(),
                color = Color.Black,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Preview of the layout:**

[image: Compose Layout Preview]

I'd like to have the items width be the same as the largest item in the list.

Notice the `.horizontalScroll(horizontalScrollState)`, this is to allow horizontal scrolling.

**What I'd like:**

[image: Desirable Layout Preview]

I need to use a `LazyColumn` but if I could use a `Column` I'd write it this way:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Blue)
        .horizontalScroll(horizontalScrollState)
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
) {
    repeat(5) { index ->
        Text(
            text = getRandomString((index + 1) * 4).uppercase(),
            color = Color.Black,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need horizontal scroll? Does the width of your longest text exceed the width of its container and if it does you want to scroll horizontally to view it?

Comment: @Johann Yes, the items will have different width which will exceed the parent container width so it will need to be scrollable horizontally to reveal all the items fully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to calculate width of the widest element separately. You can do it by placing an invisible copy of you cell with widest content in a `Box` along with `LazyColumn`.

   In your sample it's easy - just get the longest string. If in the real project you can't decide which of contents is gonna be the widest one, you have two options:

   1.1. Place all of them one on top of each other. You can do it only if you have some limited number of cells,

   1.2. Otherwise you have to made some approximation and filter a short list of the ones you expect to be the widest ones.
2. Because of `horizontalScroll` `maxWidth` constraint is infinity, you have to pass calculated width manually. You can get it with `onSizeChanged`:

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen(
) {
    fun getRandomString(length: Int): String {
        val allowedChars = ('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z') + ('0'..'9')
        return (1..length)
            .map { allowedChars.random() }
            .joinToString("")
    }

    val items = remember {
        List(30) { index ->
            getRandomString((index + 1) * 4).uppercase()
        }
    }
    val maxLengthItem = remember(items) {
        items.maxByOrNull { it.length }
    }
    val (maxLengthItemWidthDp, setMaxLengthItemWidthDp) = remember {
        mutableStateOf<Dp?>(null)
    }

    val horizontalScrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Box(
        Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .horizontalScroll(horizontalScrollState)
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            items(items) { item ->
                Cell(
                    item,
                    modifier = if (maxLengthItemWidthDp != null) {
                        Modifier.width(maxLengthItemWidthDp)
                    } else {
                        Modifier
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        if (maxLengthItem != null) {
            val density = LocalDensity.current
            Cell(
                maxLengthItem,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .requiredWidthIn(max = Dp.Infinity)
                    .onSizeChanged {
                        setMaxLengthItemWidthDp(with(density) { it.width.toDp() })
                    }
                    .alpha(0f)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Cell(
    item: String,
    modifier: Modifier,
) {
    Text(
        text = item,
        color = Color.Black,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .background(Color.Yellow)
    )
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible when horizontal srolling is enabled.

> Regular Modifier.fillMaxWidth can't work inside the scrolling
> horizontally layouts as the items are measured with
> Constraints.Infinity as the constraints for the main axis.

If you want your Column solution to work, you need to place it inside another contain (like a Box) and apply horizontal scrolling to the parent. Scrolling on the Column itself needs to be removed:

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .requiredWidth(250.dp)
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)

    ) {
        repeat(5) { index ->
            Text(
                text = getRandomString((index + 1) * 40).uppercase(),
                color = Color.Black,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Also, your alternative solution using a Column will not work either." Actually it works perfectly, I tested it. The only problem is that all the items rendered because it's not lazy.

Comment: Actually your Column solution will work, but I noticed that the width of the Column will vary to accomodate the maximum width. No sure if that is what you want. Pretty sure most developers would prefer a list that has a fixed width or at least takes up the entire screen width.

Comment: Yes, that's desired as otherwise the `Column` will not be scrollable horizontally unless you want to set a custom with but then it would clip the items. Hopefully somebody has some ideas how to do this maybe using a modified version of `LazyColumn`.

Comment: I updated my post and included a way to have a fixed list width while still allowing for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun PreviewLayout() {
    fun getRandomString(length: Int): String {
        val allowedChars = ('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z') + ('0'..'9')
        return (1..length)
            .map { allowedChars.random() }
            .joinToString("")
    }
    val horizontalScrollState = rememberScrollState()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .horizontalScroll(horizontalScrollState)

    ) {
        items(5) { index ->
            Text(
                text = getRandomString((index + 1) * 4).uppercase(),
                color = Color.Black,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .width(width = 200.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work.