# Jetpack Compose: Equal width columns of dynamic content

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have some dynamic content and I need to render it as a `LazyRow` of several `Column`s. Each `Column` can have `Text`s of various lengths.

Ideally, I would like every `Column` to be the size of the largest `Column`.

How can I ensure that every `Column` is the same width?

I think I need `IntrinsicSize` here but I'm not sure how to apply it in my case:

```
LazyRow {
    items(items = steps) {
        Column { 
            // ... dynamic content, including Texts of varying sizes and lengths
            // How can I ensure that EVERY column is the SAME width?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70094594/6550449