How to make the first element of each row in Jetpack Compose take the maximum width?
In my case the first element in each row can be of different widths how can I make them all have the same maximum width?
I placed the elements in 2 different columns but then it's hard to align them vertically
So I need to somehow calculate the maximum width of each first element, and then assign it to all the first elements
expected layout

can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75236617/dynamic-item-width-in-column-jetpack-compose if it helps adn this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70091840/make-lazycolumn-items-be-as-large-as-the-largest-item-in-the-list

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Raghunandan SubcomposeLayout is what I was looking for, thx
